# Integrable function using tonelli and fubini

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x,y) = (x-\frac{1}{2})^{-3}\qquad\text{if  } 0<y<|x-\frac{1}{2}|^a$ and zero otherswise.

a) For what $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is $f$ Lebesgue integrable?

b) For $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is integrable, cumpute $$\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}f(x,y)d\lambda_2(x,y).$$

a) Well I first wrote (using Tonelli) $\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}|f(x,y)|d\lambda_2(x,y) = \int_0^{|x-\frac{1}{2}|^a}\int_0^1|x-\frac{1}{2}|dxdy$

and then I tried computing $\int_0^1|x-\frac{1}{2}|dx$ and I got $1/4$. Thus I'am left with $\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{|x-1/2|^a}dy = \frac{1}{4}|x-1/2|^a$ which doesn't help.

Then I thought, that the exercise probably wants me to compute the integral the other way round. So I tried $\int_0^1\int_0^{|x-\frac{1}{2}|^a}|x-\frac{1}{2}|^{3}dydx$ And got $\int_0^1\frac{|x-\frac{1}{2}|^a}{|x-\frac{1}{2}|^3}dx=\int_0^1|x-\frac{1}{2}|^{a-3}dx.$ I put $\int_0^1|x-\frac{1}{2}|^{a-3}dx$ in mathematica and it spat $\frac{2^{3-a}}{a-2}$ out, for $a>2$.

So now I have two questions: Why are the two results not equal? (Or are they, and I just do not see it?) I don't think conditions for Tonelli are violated.

How do I find values for $a$ without computing $\int_0^1|x-\frac{1}{2}|^{a-3}dx$?

Comment: I just saw that I forgot the $|.|^{-3}$ in the first part. Dang it.

Comment: Okay, I got 0 for the first integral; but still the same questions remain.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are forgetting to split up the integral over the absolute value boundary.  Remember that for $x<\frac{1}{2}$, $|x-\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{2}-x$.  So here's how you do the computation:

As $[0,1]$ is $\sigma$-finite, we can apply Tonelli to get
\begin{equation*}\int\limits_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}f(x,y)\;d(x,y)=\int_0^1\int_0^{|x-\frac{1}{2}|^a}(x-\textstyle\frac{1}{2})^{-3}\;dy\;dx\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}=\int_0^1(x-\textstyle\frac{1}{2})^{-3}\displaystyle\left(\int_0^{|x-\frac{1}{2}|^a}\;dy\right)dx\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}=\int_0^1(x-\textstyle\frac{1}{2})^{-3}|x-\frac{1}{2}|^a\;dx\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}=\int_\frac{1}{2}^1(x-\textstyle\frac{1}{2})^{a-3}\;dx+\displaystyle\int_0^\frac{1}{2}(\textstyle\frac{1}{2}-x)^{a-3}\;dx\end{equation*}
which, so long as $a\neq 2$ (see below for the case $a=2$), gives:
\begin{equation*}=\left[\frac{(x-\textstyle\frac{1}{2})^{a-2}}{a-2}\right]_\frac{1}{2}^1-\displaystyle\left[\frac{(\textstyle\frac{1}{2}-x)^{a-2}}{a-2}\right]_0^\frac{1}{2}\end{equation*}
This quantity is undefined for $a<2$, so we must assume $a>2$, yielding:
\begin{equation*}=\left[\frac{(\textstyle\frac{1}{2})^{a-2}}{a-2}\right]-\displaystyle\left[\frac{-(\textstyle\frac{1}{2})^{a-2}}{a-2}\right]\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}=2\left[\frac{(\textstyle\frac{1}{2})^{a-2}}{a-2}\right]=\frac{2^{3-a}}{a-2}\end{equation*}

Note that if $a=2$ then the antiderivative involves a logarithm, which turns out to be undefined for the integral limits.  So $\int_{[0,1]^2}f(x,y)\;d(x,y)=2^{3-a}(a-2)^{-1}$ for $a>2$ and is undefined for $a\leq 2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Ben Wallis. As we do not know whether $f$ is integrable or not, we cannot apply Fubini. But Tonelli seems to be applicable. But doesen't Tonelli state that if $\int_{[0,1]×[0,1]}|f(x,y)|dλ_2(x,y)$ exists, also the iterated integrals exist, and that they're equal?
You have nicely shown, that $\int_0^1\int_0^{|x-1/2|^a}dydx$ exists and is equal to $\frac{2^{3-a}}{a-2}$. But then $\int_0^{|x-1/2|^a}\int_0^1dxdy$ should exist as well, right? But if I compute:

Comment: $\int_0^{|x-1/2|^a}\int_0^1|x-1/2|^{-3}dxdy$, then 

\begin{align*}\int_0^1|x-1/2|^{-3}dx &=\int_0^{1/2}(1/2-x)^{-3}dx+\int_{1/2}^1(x-1/2)^{-3}dx\\ &= \frac{2}{(1-2x)^2}|_0^{1/2}-\frac{2}{(1-2x)^2}|_{1/2}^1\\ &= -4\end{align*} but you divide by zero everytime you plug in $1/2$. Ignoring that, $-4\int_0^{|x-1/2|^a}dy\neq \frac{2^{3-a}}{a-2}$.
How is that possible??

Comment: @DerDieDasEhochWas you are correct that I should have used Tonelli instead of Fubini. Fixed. As to your second comment, you can't divide by zero which is why we must have $a>2$. The reverse order integration doesn't work as you wrote it. You need to adjust the bounds, which becomes something kinda nasty.

Comment: Hm, okay. Another thing: how do you see, that \begin{equation*}=\left[\frac{(x-\textstyle\frac{1}{2})^{a-2}}{a-2}\right]_\frac{1}{2}^1-\displaystyle\left[\frac{(\textstyle\frac{1}{2}-x)^{a-2}}{a-2}\right]_0^\frac{1}{2}\end{equation*} is undefined for $a<2$??